# Executing HTTP request inside a thread - Error

Tags: java, android

Following is the code of my activity I am using for sending an HTTP request to the server in a new thread. However, there is a syntactical error that I'm not able to figure out.

Following is the error I am getting

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete       ClassInstanceCreationExpression
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

I'm new to Java. Please help.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

    /*
     * Event listener for registration button. This will load the loading view and fire up the HTTP request to the server
     */
    public OnClickListener registrationBtnListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){

                    String urlParameters = "";

                    try {
                        urlParameters = "fName=" + URLEncoder.encode("John", "UTF-8") +
                        "&lName=" + URLEncoder.encode("Smith", "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Http.post("http://192.168.1.101/project/test.php", urlParameters);
                }
            }
            trd.run();
        }
    };
```

EDIT :

Fixed by adding a ); before trd.run(). But now, I get a different error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass 
     method
    - implements java.lang.Runnable.run
```

Following is the code :

```
Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){

                    String urlParameters = "";

                    try {
                        urlParameters = "fName=" + URLEncoder.encode("yash", "UTF-8") +
                        "&lName=" + URLEncoder.encode("desai", "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Http.post("http://192.168.1.101/bworld/test.php", urlParameters);
                }
            });
```

The error is on this line :

```
public void run(){
```

Comment: Which line is that error referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re second error.  I think the problem is the `@Override` annotation.  If you are compiling with Java 1.5 as source level, that annotation means that you need to override a method in a superclass.  But you are (just) implementing a method in an interface.

Either remove the annotation, or change the source level to Java 1.6 or later.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing `)` in `new Thread(...`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution fixed the error. But now i'm getting a different error as edited in my post.